# В многомерном массиве вывести ключи с общим значением в виде таблицы. Php

Tags: php, массивы

У меня - многомерный массив работников. Нужно вывести работников в зависимости от компании в виде списка.
Например,

Microsoft

- Sergey
- Roman
- Yura

Amazon

- Olja

Понимаю, что выполняется через перебор массива foreach, но не знаю как вывести ключи. Может, конечно, через условие и конкатенацию...

```
$staff = [
[
    'Name' => 'Serhii',
    'Company' => 'Microsoft',
    'Position' => 'Developer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Oleh',
    'Company' => 'Apple',
    'Position' => 'QC Engineer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Olya',
    'Company' => 'Amazon',
    'Position' => 'Project Manager',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Andrii',
    'Company' => 'Apple',
    'Position' => 'Solution Architect',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Ihor',
    'Company' => 'Samsung',
    'Position' => 'Engineer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Olesya',
    'Company' => 'Samsung',
    'Position' => 'Developer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Roman',
    'Company' => 'Microsoft',
    'Position' => 'Product Owner',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Yura',
    'Company' => 'Microsoft',
    'Position' => 'QC Enginee',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Iryna',
    'Company' => 'ITStep',
    'Position' => 'Teacher',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Oksana',
    'Company' => 'ITStep',
    'Position' => 'Teacher',
],
];
```

Comment: `... foreach($array as $key => $value) {... ` $key - ключ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так: нужный список лежит тут `$companyEmployees`

```
$staff = [
[
    'Name' => 'Serhii',
    'Company' => 'Microsoft',
    'Position' => 'Developer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Oleh',
    'Company' => 'Apple',
    'Position' => 'QC Engineer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Olya',
    'Company' => 'Amazon',
    'Position' => 'Project Manager',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Andrii',
    'Company' => 'Apple',
    'Position' => 'Solution Architect',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Ihor',
    'Company' => 'Samsung',
    'Position' => 'Engineer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Olesya',
    'Company' => 'Samsung',
    'Position' => 'Developer',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Roman',
    'Company' => 'Microsoft',
    'Position' => 'Product Owner',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Yura',
    'Company' => 'Microsoft',
    'Position' => 'QC Enginee',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Iryna',
    'Company' => 'ITStep',
    'Position' => 'Teacher',
],
[
    'Name' => 'Oksana',
    'Company' => 'ITStep',
    'Position' => 'Teacher',
],
];
$companyEmployees = array();
foreach ($staff as $staffItem)
        $companyEmployees[$staffItem['Company']][]=$staffItem['Name'];

var_dump($companyEmployees);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Реально помогли.